# Forwarding homepage to landing page using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, forwarding

I have a Wordpress site (eg. www.domain.com) that lands on the homepage. I want to change this, so it actually lands on an interior page (eg. www.domain.com/landing/). I don't want to do a standard redirect, as I still want to allow access to the homepage. I just want to change the initial landing page.

I'm assuming it's a matter of updating the ".htaccess" file, but I just want to find a solution that will still allow me to access the homepage of the site, once I've landed on the landing page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the wordpress dashboard/customise your site. Set your static front page to the new landing page.

Comment: This doesn't work, as it removes access to the homepage (when I click on the logo, it takes me to the landing page, instead of the homepage). It also shifts some of the styling of this landing page around (removes sidebar, and applies homepage styling).

Comment: What theme are you using here? Is the landing page a custom page?

Comment: It's a custom page. The homepage template is full width, and the landing page template has a left sidebar. When I try applying the landing page in the wordpress dashboard, the sidebar appears above the content for some reason.

Comment: You could change the logo url in header.php to point to the old home page. Check your landing page template is still set to the correct php file after setting as the static front page.

Comment: I tried this as well, but it didn't seem to work either. I've come up with another solution. Although not as ideal, it will work for what I need it for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the referer to make sure it's either someone who typed the URL in the address bar or clicking a link elsewhere:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /landing/ [L,R]
```

You'd want this above your wordpress rules.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working either. It forwards www.domain.com to www.domain.com/landing/ – but again, the homepage becomes inaccessible. Any time you try to click a link to take you to the homepage, it forwards again to the landing page.